# Using Grep with Xargs and Process Substitution

Tags: grep, pipe, stdin, xargs, process-substitution

I'm trying to pass the grep query through xargs while passing the file through process substitution.

```
command1 | xargs -I{} grep {} <(command2)
```

make dummy files

```
for f in {1..50}; do echo $f >> test50.txt; done

for f in {25..30}; do echo $f >> test5.txt; done
```

xargs and process substitution with grep

```
cat test5.txt | xargs -I{} grep {} <(cat test50.txt)
```

output is :

```
25
```

desired output is :

```
25
26
27
28
29
30
```

I think the issue lies with how grep is receiving the input file, it's stopping after one line, whereas I would like it to search the entire input file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU Parallel it looks like this:

```
cat test5.txt | parallel 'grep {} <(cat test50.txt)'
```

Answer (score 4):

Consider this

`cat test5.txt | xargs -I{} echo {} <(cat test50.txt)`

which yields

```
25 /dev/fd/63
26 /dev/fd/63
27 /dev/fd/63
28 /dev/fd/63
29 /dev/fd/63
30 /dev/fd/63
```

and consequently this

`cat test5.txt | xargs -I{} cat {} <(cat test50.txt)`

outputs

```
cat: 25: No such file or directory
1
2
--cutted for brevity--
49
50
cat: 26: No such file or directory
cat: 27: No such file or directory
cat: 28: No such file or directory
cat: 29: No such file or directory
cat: 30: No such file or directory
```

Your problem is not about `grep`, but `process substitution` in bash. Process substitution creates one named pipe. Next, all data from that pipe is consumed in the **first** invocation of command supplied to `xargs` (in your example it is `grep`, in mine above `echo` and `cat`), so the one with `25` as the first argument.

This will work

`cat test5.txt | xargs -I{} bash -c " grep {} <(cat test50.txt)"`

as it creates "fresh" `process substitution` for every `grep` invocation independently.

Answer (score 2):

no need for `xargs` as `grep` already has a way to specify search terms from a file

```
$ seq 50 > f1
$ seq 25 30 > f2
$ grep -Fxf f2 f1
25
26
27
28
29
30
```

From `man grep`

> **-F, --fixed-strings**
>   Interpret PATTERN as a list of fixed strings (instead of regular expressions), separated  by  newlines,
>   any of which is to be matched.
>
> **-x, --line-regexp**
>   Select only those matches that exactly match the whole line.  For a regular expression pattern, this is
>   like parenthesizing the pattern and then surrounding it with ^ and $.
>
> **-f FILE, --file=FILE**
>   Obtain patterns from FILE, one per line.  If this option is used multiple times or is combined with the -e  (--regexp)  option,  search  for  all  patterns  given.  The empty file contains zero patterns, and therefore matches nothing.